Debugging Bot Framework Bot in Teams
I would like to debug a Bot Framework Bot on Teams, but it seems it requires an Azure Bot registration and setting the messaging endpoint, which involves several requirements, including licensing and subscriptions. I’m following the instructions from the link below utilizing VS enterprise teams toolkit. It doesn’t make sense to require an Azure Bot registration, especially in large organizations where multiple developers are involved. Would each developer need their own Azure Bot registration, as each would need to set their dev tunnel URL?
My question is: does the Bot Framework require an Azure Bot registration to debug in Teams? If not, what’s a good source to help set up Teams debugging for an existing bot?
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-people-picker-adaptive-card/csharp

Yes. To use Teams, you will need an Azure Bot resource. You can use a Free tier bot registrations, so there would be no cost for that. Each bot resource/registration would have it's own messaging endpoint, which would point to the tunnel (ngrok, dev tunnel), which would then point to the developer's machine.
